# Change Array Primary Keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Array `$users`:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => name3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => name4
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => name5
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => name6
    )

)
```

which has to look like:

```
Array
(
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [name] => name3
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [name] => name4
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [name] => name5
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [name] => name6
    )

)
```

The "primary" key of my array has to be the user-id to make it easier accessable.
so I could use:

```
$users[$userid]['name']
```

where `$userid` would be int(6) and the result would be string(name6)

I'm afraid this is pretty basic, but what would be the easiest solution for my problem?

Comment: Why can't you just store the values in the `[3]`, `[4]`, `[5]`, etc keys and leave the first 3 empty? Is there any surrounding code?

Comment: i create that array with a mysqli query

Comment: So you should better use a while loop to read the mysqli_query() and directly create the array with final keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PHP < 5.5, it's almost as simple:

```
$newUsers = array();
foreach($users as $data) {
    $newUsers[$data['id']] = $data;
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I think this is _much_ clearer than "the PHP 5.5 solution".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PHP >= 5.5, it can be as simple as

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_column($oldArray, 'id'),
    $oldArray
);
```

For earlier versions of PHP, you can use

```
$newArray = array_combine(
    array_map(
        function($value) {
            return $value['id'];
        },
        $oldArray
    ),
    $oldArray
);
```

Comment: Caution, missing coma before $oldArray, and the closure is only possible since PHP 5.3 if I remember.

Comment: If anybody is using PHP < 5.3, then they really should upgrade because 5.3 is no longer supported.... thanks for spotting the missing comma though

Answer (score 1):

> i create that array with a mysqli query

Why not generate your array with the keys you want in the first place?
Rather than changing them after-the-fact?

So instead of something like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   $result[] = $row;
```

something like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   $result[$row['id']] = $row;
```

Comment: i have my basic mysqli querys in an extra class file. the first code snippet (which is exaktly mine) has a much wider field of use. i will concider an upgrade, thank you!

Comment: @Stefan: In my codebases I tend to have my "do this query please" function take an optional `$key` argument. When this is set, `$result[$row[$key]]` is used as I show in my second snippet; when it is not, `$result[]` is used. It works very well and keeps your code generic. It's _far_ more efficient and elegant than later translating your results into another form in some _X%_ of cases.